# MongoDB - Calculate $sum of values in array containing array elements

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation query producing an array containing array elements. How can I $sum the values and produce output similar to the following:

```
  { "additionalReminders": 7 }
```

This is an example of the data structure. Notice some of the array elements are empty and should be ignored or counted as 0:

```
  {
    "additionalReminders": [
      [
        "1",
        "1"
      ],
      [],
      [],
      [
        "1"
      ],
      [],
      [
        "1"
      ],
      [],
      [
        "1"
      ],
      [],
      [
        "1"
      ],
      [],
      [],
      [
        "1"
      ]
    ]
  }
```

Mongo Playground:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/BjSU_oYC8KG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you're looking for:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$additionalReminders"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$additionalReminders"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      "additionalReminders": {
        $sum: {
          "$toInt": "$additionalReminders"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: false,
      additionalReminders: true
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/JInbHAmc_yV

The idea is to unwind your field a couple of times so as to get this output:

```
...
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "additionalReminders": "1"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "additionalReminders": "1"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "additionalReminders": "1"
  },
...
```

Then it's just a simple matter of summing up the `$additionalReminders` field, but not before we cast it to an Int.